# A_app launch B_app independent on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

In B's manifest as below:

```
<activity android:name="BActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTION_TEST" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And had a Global variable.

In A's launch code as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package name","package name.BActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It can launch B_app successly.
But while I launch B from A and direct launch B by click B's icon,  the Global variable are the same between them.
I want to B launched from A and launched directly are 2 independent app.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leaunch your Activity B from A you could pass some boolean to B stating that it has been launched from A. For Example launch your activity A from B as follows:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package name", "package name.BActivity"));
b.putBoolean("fromA", true);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your Activity B then you check if you have any bundle in `onCreate()` as follows

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        // Activity launched from Activity A
    } else
    {
        // Actitivity launched from launcher  
            // clear the global variables
    }
}
```

If it is launched from the launcher then you can clear away the global variables.

Comment: But the 2 launched at the same time, the global variables will be clear.

Comment: What do you mean 2 launched at the same time? If you dont want to clear the variables, dont clear them. Just **dont use them** when you are launching from the launcher, otherwise use them.

Comment: In general, you should *never* rely on global variables (i.e. statics) in Android.  Android, at any point in time, could choose to kill your process (for example if a phone call comes in).  Upon completion of the phone call, Android would launch a new instance of your process in a new VM and the statics you are relying on would be  cleared.

Comment: @EJK I agree! the correct way would be store the required data in the SharedPreferences